# How to know "keys" for Entity::create()

Tags: 8, entities

The [document](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21Entity.php/function/Entity%3A%3Acreate/8.2.x) says `Entity::create()` takes

> "$values (optional) An array of values to set, keyed by property name"

as an arguement.

I also found snippets like

```
$term = Term::create([
    'name' => $term_name,
    'vid' => $vocabulary_name,
  ]);
```

and they worked.

But how exactly do you know what kind of values can be set in the array?
In the case above, where did people take the keys `'name'` and `'vid'` from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the of `baseFieldDefinitions` method in [class Term](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21taxonomy%21src%21Entity%21Term.php/class/Term/8.2.x):

Here is a list of fields you can set in create Term:

1. `tid` : Term ID
2. `uuid` : The term UUID.
3. `vid`: The vocabulary to which the term is assigned.
4. `langcode` : The term language code.
5. `name` : Name of term.
6. `description` : description of term
7. `weight` : weight of term.
8. `parent` : Term parent.

Example:

```
$term = Term::create([
    'name' => 'term name',
    'vid' => 'tags',
    'status' => 1,
    'tid' => 13,
    'uuid' => 1,
    'langcode' => 'en',
    'description' => 'tags description',
    'weight' => -12,
    //'parent' => parent tid
  ]);
  $term->save();
```

Answer (score 1):

Load an existing term

```
$term = Term::load(1);
```

or create an empty term to get the vocabulary specific bundle fields

```
$term = Term::create([
  'vid' => $vocabulary_name,
]);
```

and dump it as an array:

```
var_dump($term->toArray());
```